# How to detect if dompdf is processing a local script

Tags: php, dompdf

I am using dompdf with DOMPDF_ENABLE_REMOTE set to true.

I do this so that pdfs can be generated from an html template with dynamic images.  For example:

```
<img src='http://www.myserver.com/generateThumb.php?src=img.jpg' />
```

Both dompdf and the generateThumb script are on the same server.

Inside of generateThumb.php, I want to add authentication.

This is easy for when generateThumb is called directly from the browser - I just authenticate against the user session ($_SESSION).

However, when I do this, and dompdf processes the html, the authentication fails.

How can I check (inside of generateThumb) if the dompdf script is doing the calling.

Thanks (in advance) for your help.

Comment: Is generateThumb.php a library or a custom script? Is the authentication code custom or baked in?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, testing `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` should be more than enough...